# Extending Ruby with C++, how is it possible to require a rb-File from Memory?

Tags: c++, embedded-ruby

I am rummaging for time in the Rubysource and i am trying to extend Ruby with C++. My question is, cause it's really hard to find something in the Rubycode: How can I interpret ruby-code from Memory instead of a file.
My point is, that i want to interpret my own encrypted ruby code from Memory.
My current code for interpreting a ruby file looks so:

```
bool Ruby::rb_load_file(char* szFilename)
{
    ::ruby_script(szFilename);
    int ret = 0;
    VALUE value;
    rb_protect((VALUE(*)(VALUE))rb_require, (VALUE)szFilename, &ret);
    value = ::rb_gv_get("$!");
    value = ::rb_funcall(value, rb_intern("to_s"), 0);
    if (rb_string_value_cstr(&value)[0] != '\0')
    {
        ::rb_eval_string_protect("puts $!, $@", &ret);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But i don't want load my ruby file from my harddisc but from my memory (with observance of the utf-8 encodings, so rb_eval_string will not work).
A better thinking approach: I want interpret my ruby code as c-string with observance of the utf-8 encodings inklusive bom.

Comment: Off the top of my head, you should be able to use a memory mapped file for this.

Comment: I don't understand how memory mapped files can help me? Can you explain that in more detail?